# In rally how to update customize field through Automation which is having drop down scenario

Tags: rally

Am trying to update customize field through scripts which is having drop down field.I tried updating by using type of the field(AllowedAttributeValue).

I have created a Query for this field with type mentioned above , but its giving null response. This field is similar to tags field, but its customize .

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

```
QueryRequest tagRequest = new QueryRequest("TypeDefinition")
tagRequest.setWorkspace("/workspace/")
tagRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("_refObjectName","ObjectID","StringValue"))
tagRequest.setQueryFilter QueryFilter("StringValue", "=", "nn"))
QueryResponse tagQueryResponse = restApi.query(tagRequest)
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code?  That will help us help you!

Comment: I have added code for reference